# Firebird Error in Creating Trigger

Tags: triggers, generator, firebird, firebird2.1, flamerobin

```
Preparing query:     CREATE TRIGGER autoincrementor_id FOR ID
    ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
    AS
    BEGIN
     IF (NEW.OID IS NULL) THEN
     NEW.OID = GEN_ID(MY_GEN_ID,1)
    Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
    Context: Statement::Prepare(     CREATE TRIGGER autoincrementor_id FOR ID
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
IF (NEW.OID IS NULL) THEN
NEW.OID = GEN_ID(MY_GEN_ID,1) )
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

SQL Message : -104
Invalid token

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Unexpected end of command - line 6, column 33
```

I get this error while creating the trigger below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER autoincrementor_id FOR ID
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
IF (NEW.OID IS NULL) THEN
NEW.OID = GEN_ID(MY_GEN_ID,1);
END
```

Where am I missing? I already have my table `ID` created with a primary id `oid`, that must be auto incremented. I also created my generator function `MY_GEN_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the statement terminator and use it to terminate the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, ie

```
SET TERM ^;

CREATE TRIGGER autoincrementor_id FOR ID
  ... rest of the trigger's body
END^

SET TERM ;^
```